# Is it an adaptive algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, computer-science

By adaptive algorithm, I understand an algorithm that changes your behavior at a time is running.

So, a CSV file handler algorithm that loads all the file into the memory if the file is small and load the file into chunks if the file is too large to fit in memory.

And handle the commit in memory if can’t write into the disk because the line changed is longer than it will replace or because it’s not appending a new line into the end of the file.

And, another example, an algorithm that serves as a Key-Value API that **changes your memory storage approach** from hash to a Tree depending the Keys values to archive better performance.

Is it both an adaptive algorithm or just an algorithm with memory management?

Comment: Direct quotation from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_algorithm): "An adaptive algorithm is an algorithm that changes its behavior at the time it is run, based on information available and on a priori defined reward mechanism (or criterion). Such information could be the story of recently received data, information on the available computational resources, or other run-time acquired (or a priori known) information related to the environment in which it operates."  Where are you stuck in applying these criteria?

Comment: @Prune, I am trying to find libraries that already implement these approaches -- Like the Key-Value algorithm mentioned -- and I am doubtful if I am assimilating the concept well. So this question is a validation for me.